# symbolic link does not work when using it for cv2.so

Tags: python, opencv, modules

I followed a tutorial online for installing `opencv4` on raspberry pi. Everything works except when trying to create a symbolic link to my `cv2.so`.
It appears to be working but I can only import cv2 module inside the `/usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.7` directory if I'm outside, I get the :

```
ModuleNotFindError" no module named "cv2"
```

Comment: Did you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21511572/6602159) out?

Comment: A Python module is more than just a shared library, there's also an `__init__.py` file and some config and loader files. Manually linking to the shared library is the wrong approach. The name of the shared library is also wrong, it should contain the Python version and the architecture, for example: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so`.
Usually, if you compile OpenCV from source and then `make install`, it is installed correctly as a Python module, why are you doing it manually? Please link to the tutorial you followed.

Comment: I don't have site-packages only "dist-packages":
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages $ ls
pip  pip-20.0.2.dist-info

the tutorial:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/?unapproved=767229&moderation-hash=738212f059bc93f40064e44c51f12934&submitted_comment=1#comment-767229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "Fixed" it by creating an virtual environment for opencv.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.